# How to Centre an object in any cell of an 8x8 grid in p5.js framework

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

This is my code of making a chess game.

```js
let pawn1; //variable for object
var offset = 10;
function setup(){
 createCanvas(600,600); // canvas
 pawn1 = new Pawn(); // pawn1 is a new Pawn object
}

function draw(){
 background(0); //black background
 checkboard();  //to make an 8x8 grid 
 pawn1.show();  //shows pawn1 object on canvas
 drag();        //allows the pawn object to be dragged
}

function Pawn(){
 this.x = 25; // x position of object
 this.y = 25; // y position of object
 this.w = 20; // width of object
 this.h = 20; // height of object

 this.show = function(){
  fill(255); // object is white
  rect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h); //object is a rectangle with x,y,w,h variables
 }
}

// grid maker function
function checkboard(){
 for (var x = 0; x < width; x += width / 8) {
  for (var y = 0; y < height; y += height / 8) {
   stroke(255); //grid lines is white
   strokeWeight(1); // lines drawn are 1 units thick
   line(x, 0, x, height); // vertical lines
   line(0, y, width, y); // horizontal lines
  }
 }
}

function drag(){
    // if mouse is clicked down and inside of the dimensions of the object then:
 if(mouseIsPressed){
  if(mouseX > pawn1.x && mouseY > pawn1.y){
   if(mouseX<(pawn1.x+pawn1.w) && mouseY<(pawn1.y+pawn1.h)){
                //square will move with the mouse pointer 
    pawn1.x = mouseX - offset;
    pawn1.y = mouseY - offset;
   }
  }
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.9.0/p5.js"></script>
```

I do not have any idea of how to make sure when the **dragged object is dropped, that it will be centered in the cell it has been dropped in.** I suppose the code would go in the " *drag* function " as an else statement but other than that I am stuck. Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate the width and height of a cell. e.g:

```js
var cell_w = width / 8;
var cell_h = height / 8;
```

I the width and height of a cell is fixed then you can use constant values, too. e.g:

```js
var cell_w = 75;
var cell_h = 75;
```

Calculate the index of the current cell, be dividing the current mouse position, by the size of a cell and truncating the result by [`int()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/int) . e.g.:

```js
var cell_ix = int(mouseX / cell_w);
var cell_iy = int(mouseY / cell_h);
```

Calculate the center point of the cell where the mouse is on:

```js
var cell_cx = (cell_ix+0.5) * cell_w;
var cell_cy = (cell_iy+0.5) * cell_h;
```

Calculate the new position of the object, dependent on the center of the cell and the size of the object:

```js
pawn1.x = cell_cx - pawn1.w/2;
pawn1.y = cell_cy - pawn1.h/2;
```

You can do that in the [`mouseReleased()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/mouseReleased) call back. That causes, that the object can be smoothly dragged, but immediately "jumps" to the center of the cell when the mouse is released:

```js
function mouseReleased() {
    if (mouseX > pawn1.x && mouseY > pawn1.y &&
        mouseX<(pawn1.x+pawn1.w) && mouseY<(pawn1.y+pawn1.h)) {

        var cell_w = width / 8;
        var cell_h = height / 8;

        var cell_ix = int(mouseX / cell_w);
        var cell_iy = int(mouseY / cell_h);

        var cell_cx = (cell_ix+0.5) * cell_w;
        var cell_cy = (cell_iy+0.5) * cell_h;

        pawn1.x = cell_cx - pawn1.w/2;
        pawn1.y = cell_cy - pawn1.h/2;
    }
}
```

See the example, where I've added the function to your original code:

```js
let pawn1; //variable for object
var offset = 10;
function setup(){
    createCanvas(600,600); // canvas
    pawn1 = new Pawn(); // pawn1 is a new Pawn object
}

function draw(){
    background(0); //black background
    checkboard();  //to make an 8x8 grid    
    pawn1.show();  //shows pawn1 object on canvas
    drag();        //allows the pawn object to be dragged
}

function Pawn(){
    this.x = 25; // x position of object
    this.y = 25; // y position of object
    this.w = 20; // width of object
    this.h = 20; // height of object

    this.show = function(){
        fill(255); // object is white
        rect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h); //object is a rectangle with x,y,w,h variables
    }
}

// grid maker function
function checkboard(){
    for (var x = 0; x < width; x += width / 8) {
        for (var y = 0; y < height; y += height / 8) {
            stroke(255); //grid lines is white
            strokeWeight(1); // lines drawn are 1 units thick
            line(x, 0, x, height); // vertical lines
            line(0, y, width, y); // horizontal lines
        }
    }
}

function drag(){
    // if mouse is clicked down and inside of the dimensions of the object then:
    if(mouseIsPressed){
        if(mouseX > pawn1.x && mouseY > pawn1.y){
            if(mouseX<(pawn1.x+pawn1.w) && mouseY<(pawn1.y+pawn1.h)){
                //square will move with the mouse pointer 
                pawn1.x = mouseX - offset;
                pawn1.y = mouseY - offset;
            }
        }
    }
}

function mouseReleased() {
    if (mouseX > pawn1.x && mouseY > pawn1.y &&
        mouseX<(pawn1.x+pawn1.w) && mouseY<(pawn1.y+pawn1.h)) {

        var cell_w = width / 8;
        var cell_h = height / 8;
        
        var cell_ix = int(mouseX / cell_w);
        var cell_iy = int(mouseY / cell_h);

        var cell_cx = (cell_ix+0.5) * cell_w;
        var cell_cy = (cell_iy+0.5) * cell_h;

        pawn1.x = cell_cx - pawn1.w/2;
        pawn1.y = cell_cy - pawn1.h/2;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.9.0/p5.js"></script>
```